# What's the Predicative of the sentence `Our duty is to make our environment better.`?

Tags: grammar

```
Our duty is to make our environment better.
```

What's the Predicative of it? is `to make`  or `to make our environment better`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Our duty is* [*to make our environment better*].

The predicative complement (PC) is the whole of the bracketed expression.

It’s intended as a subtype of ascriptive PC: it ascribes a purpose to the predicand, "our duty".